# Convert CFML to CFScript using CFHtmlToPdf

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I'm trying to convert my CFML code to CFScript, but I am getting an error with CFHtmlToPdf.

**CFML:**

```
<cfoutput>
  <cfhtmltopdf orientation="portrait"  pagetype="A4" margintop="1" marginbottom="1" name=pdfFile>
    #arguments.data.HTMLData#
  </cfhtmltopdf>

  <cfmail type=HTML to="#arguments.data.Email#" from="support@mydomain.com" subject="Form Test" server="localhost">
    TEST
    <cfmailparam file="#arguments.data.ReportName#.pdf" type="application/pdf" content="#pdfFile#"/>
  </cfmail>
</cfoutput>
```

**My cfscript code:**

```
cfhtmltopdf(source=arguments.data.HTMLData, destination=pdfPath);

mailerService = new mail();
mailerService.setTo("arguments.data.Email"); 
mailerService.setFrom("support@mydomain.com"); 
mailerService.setSubject("Form Test"); 
mailerService.setType("html");
mailerService.addParam(file="Test.pdf",type="application/pdf",content=pdfPath);
mailerService.send(body="Test");
```

I'm getting the error:

> Either the src is not a proper URL or the file specified by absolute path does not exist.

The error occurs in the line:

```
cfhtmltopdf(source=arguments.data.HTMLData, destination=pdfPath);
```

Am I using CFHtmlToPdf incorrectly in cfscript?

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Do a writedump of arguments.data,HTMLData.

Comment: Kind of hard to spot the issue when all we can see is variable names . What's the actual *value* of those two variables?

Comment: It is just HTML tags in the arguments.data,HTMLData varaible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you were using `cfhtmltopdf` in the wrong way. The HTML string should be passed not as the `source` attribute, but as a content of the function(like what you would do for a `savecontent`).

Check this [link](https://cfdocs.org/cfhtmltopdf).

```
variables.pdfFile='';
cfhtmltopdf(name='variables.pdfFile'){
  writeOutput(arguments.data.HTMLData);
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, I am getting the error: variable pdfFile is undefined. How can I define a variable that will contain a pdf?

Comment: I think the issue is that you need to put variable name in quotes`"variables.pdfFile"`

Comment: Thanks. Got it. The only problem is that I have in my HTML an image in the format image/svg+xml;base64 and the cfhtmltopdf cannot display the image in the PDF